# Inkscape show nothing when I open .svg that I can see using my web browser?

Tags: inkscape

I've got [this .svg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9O7sxdAf2xjWFZpNi1LR012b00) exported using Fritling I can open it using my web browser but when I try to open it using Inkscape I can't see anything only a couple of borders.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm no Inkscape expert, but the linked file opens fine in Adobe Illustrator (apart from some missing fonts) so maybe you need to try a different file format for import to Inkscape.

Comment: Can confirm. SVG looks OK on OSX quick view. Inkscape shows nothing, although objects can be selected, path nodes edited, etc. Tried changing fill / stroke / hidden / locked properties to no avail. Still invisible.

Comment: I'm currently using Inkscape 0.92pre2 15127 on a Windows 7 machine, and the svg is visible. What is your version?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini 0.91 WINDOWS ans LINUX

Comment: I suggest you to upgrade your version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1294784) in Inkscape v0.91 and prior, that makes your image invisible when a font-size of 0 is used. The bug is fixed in the upcoming v0.92 release.

For now, you can quickfix your file by replacing all occurrences of `font-size="0"` with `display="none"` using a text editor.

If you replace `font-size="0"` with `font-size="5"`, the texts become visible again in Inkscape, so you can remove them manually.